# Unable to change website background color using CSS html

Tags: html, css, background-color

```css
* { 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html, body { 
 height:100%;
}
body { 
 background:#fff; 
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:100%; 
 line-height:1.25em;
 color:#999;
}

img {
 border:0; 
 vertical-align:top; 
 text-align:left;
}
object { 
 vertical-align:top; 
 outline:none;
}
ul, ol { 
 list-style:none;
}

.fleft { 
 float:left;
}
.fright { 
 float:right;
}
.clear { 
 clear:both;
}

.col-1, .col-2, .col-3 { 
 float:left;
}

.alignright { 
 text-align:right;
}
.aligncenter { 
 text-align:center;
}

.wrapper { 
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.container { 
 width:100%;
}




/*==== GLOBAL =====*/
.inner-page {
 width:864px; 
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:150px 0 0 0;
 font-size:.8125em;
 position:relative;
}

.header {
 height:149px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
 .header.small {
  height:110px;
 }
 
 
.content {
 padding:0 0 60px 0;
}
.footer {
 padding:2px 4px 20px 0;
 background:url(images/footer-bg.gif) left top repeat-x;
 text-align:right;
}

.page {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:1050px;
 height:100% !important;
 height:1050px;
 position:relative;
}

#services {
 background:#181818;
}

#home {
 background:#181818;
}

#contacts {
 background:#181818;
}


/*----- forms parameters -----*/

input, select, textarea { 
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:1em;
 vertical-align:middle;
 font-weight:normal;
}

/*----- other -----*/
.img-indent { 
 margin:0 20px 0 0; 
 float:left;
}
.img-box { 
 width:100%; 
 overflow:hidden; 
 padding-bottom:20px;
}
 .img-box img { 
  float:left; 
  margin:0 20px 0 0;
 }

.extra-wrap { 
 overflow:hidden;
}


p {
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
.p1 { 
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.p2 { 
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
.p3 { 
 margin-bottom:30px;
}

/*----- txt, links, lines, titles -----*/
a {
 color:#f4f4f4; 
 outline:none;
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration:none;
}



h1 {
 font-size:20px;
 line-height:1.2em;
 color:#f4f4f4;
 
}


h2 {
 font-size:16px;
 line-height:1.2em;
 color:#f4f4f4;
 margin-bottom:11px;
}
h3 {
 font-size:40px;
 color:#2c3234;
 line-height:1.2em;
 font-weight:normal;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
h4 {
 font-size:1em;
 font-weight:normal;
}


.line-ver, .line-ver1 { 
 background-image:url(images/line-ver.gif); 
 background-repeat:repeat-y;
 width:100%;
}



.link1 { 
 color:#f4f4f4;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:15px;
 padding:0 0 0 10px;
}
.link1:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
}



.address dt {
 margin-bottom:16px;
}
.address dd { 
 clear:both;
 color:#fff;
}
 .address dd span { 
  float:left;
  width:85px;
  color:#999;
 }
 .address dd a {
  color:#999;
 }


/*===== header =====*/
.header .logo {
 font-size:68px;
 line-height:1.2em;
 float:left;
}
 .header .logo a {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
 
 .header .nav {
  float:right;
 }
  .header .nav li {
   float:left;
   padding-left:5px;
  }
   .header .nav li a {
    float:left;
    width:153px;
    color:#f4f4f4;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:url(images/nav-bg.png) no-repeat left top;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:46px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
   }
   .header .nav li a:hover, .header .nav li a.current {
    background:url(images/nav-bg.png) no-repeat left -46px;
    color:#333;
   }


/*===== content =====*/
.content {
 
}
 .list1 li {
  font-size:15px;
  padding:0 0 4px 0;
 }
  .list1 li a {
   color:#f4f4f4;
   text-decoration:none;
   background:#f53502;
   display:inline-block;
   padding:4px 10px 4px 10px;
  }
  .list1 li a:hover {
   background:url(images/bg1.gif) left top;
  }
 
 
 .social-links {
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:19px 0 0 0;
 }
  .social-links li {
   display:inline;
  }
   .social-links li a {
    float:right;
    background:url(images/button-left.gif) no-repeat left top #757575;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:3px;
   }
   .social-links li a span {
    float:left;
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
    line-height:33px;
    background:url(images/button-right.gif) no-repeat right top;
    cursor:pointer;
   }
   .social-links li a:hover {
    color:#f53502;
   }
 
 
 
 .logo-big {
  padding-bottom:39px;
 }
 
 .description {
  color:#2e3436;
  font-size:17px;
  line-height:24px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-align:right;
  padding-bottom:35px;
 }

/*===== footer =====*/
.footer {
 font-size:10px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 color:#fff;
}
 .footer a {
  color:#f53502;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
 .footer a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
 }


/*----- forms -----*/
#contacts-form fieldset {
 border:none;
 width:240px;
}
 #contacts-form label {
  display:block;
  height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
  #contacts-form input {
   width:225px;
   padding:6px 5px 6px 8px;
   color:#333;
   background:#f4f4f4;
   border:none;
  }
  
  
  #contacts-form textarea {
   width:225px;
   padding:6px 5px 6px 8px;
   height:100px;
   color:#333;
   background:#f4f4f4;
   border:none;
   overflow:auto;
   margin-bottom:15px;
  }
  

/*==========================================*/



/*======== home page ============*/
 
#home .social-links li a {
 background:url(images/button-left1.gif) no-repeat left top #d9d9d9;
 color:#fff;
}
#home .social-links li a span {
 background:url(images/button-right1.gif) no-repeat right top;
}
#home .social-links li a:hover {
 color:#f53502;
}

#home .footer {
 color:#282f31;
 background:url(images/footer-bg1.gif) left top repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<meta name="description" content="asdfsfsdfsdf" />
<meta name="keywords" content="asdfsfsdfsdf" />

<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days" />
<meta name="author" content="asdfsfsdfsdf" />
<meta name="identifier-url" content="www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com" />
<meta name="distribution" content="Global" />
<meta name="coverage" content="Worldwide" />
<meta name="rating" content="General" />
<meta name="language" content="English" />


<title>asdfsfsdfsdf</title>


<style type="text/css">

div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }






@media print {
    html, body {
       display: none;  /* hide whole page */
    }
}






</style>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<link href="http://www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/js/cufon-replace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<!--[if lt IE 7]>
 <link href="http://www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/ie_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/js/ie_png.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       ie_png.fix('.png, .nav a');
   </script>
<![endif]-->





<script language="JavaScript">
  /**
    * Disable right-click of mouse, F12 key, and save key combinations on page
    * By Arthur Gareginyan (arthurgareginyan@gmail.com)
    * For full source code, visit https://mycyberuniverse.com
    */
  window.onload = function() {
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    //document.onkeydown = function(e) {
      // "I" key
      if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 73) {
        disabledEvent(e);
      }
      // "J" key
      if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 74) {
        disabledEvent(e);
      }
      // "S" key + macOS
      if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
        disabledEvent(e);
      }
      // "U" key
      if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 85) {
        disabledEvent(e);
      }
      // "F12" key
      if (event.keyCode == 123) {
        disabledEvent(e);
      }
    }, false);
    function disabledEvent(e){
      if (e.stopPropagation){
        e.stopPropagation();
      } else if (window.event){
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  };
</script>






</head>

<body bgcolor="#333" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">



 <!-- privacy page begin -->
   <div id="services" class="page">
    <div class="inner-page">
       <!-- header begin -->
       <div class="header">
          <div class="logo"><a href="http://www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/index.html"><img alt="asdfsfsdfsdf" src="http://www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/images/asdfsfsdfsdf.jpg" /></a></div>
          <ul class="nav">
               <li><a href="http://www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/index.html" class="q1">home</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <!-- header end -->
         <!-- content end -->
         <div class="content"> 



<h2>asdfsfsdfsdf™</h2>





           
<br/>*asdfsfsdfsdf


<br/>*asdfsfsdfsdf

<br/>*asdfsfsdfsdf
<br/>*asdfsfsdfsdf 
           </p>




<br>

asdfsfsdfsdf

<br><br><br><a href="http://www.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/asdfsfsdfsdf.html">Request</a> a complimentary sample pack.


<br><br><br><br>








         </div>
         <!-- content end -->
         <!-- footer begin -->
         <div class="footer">
          Copyright &copy; 2013-2018 asdfsfsdfsdf, LLC. All Rights Reserved &nbsp;<a href="http://www.m.asdfsfsdfsdf.com/index.html">view mobile</a>
         </div>
         <!-- footer end -->
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- privacy page end -->
   <!-- coded by ramzes -->
   <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Newbie here.  I've tried changing the background color at a few different points but with no luck. On a different page, it works!  I've tried to compare and contrast the different code to find the difference - also tried changing values in the external CSS file and also to the bgcolor.  Deleted temp internet files, closed browser and rebooted.  I also verified that I updated the files I need to, saved them, and then tried opening the file (to test) again in the browser.  I verified I'm opening the correct file.  Any help is truly appreciated.  Thanks.

Here's where the changed should be effected:

```
#services {
    background:#181818;
}
```

Here's some of my HTML code:

```
</head>

<body bgcolor="#333" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">



    <!-- privacy page begin -->
   <div id="services" class="page">
    <div class="inner-page">
        <!-- header begin -->
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo"><a href="http://www.example.com/index.html"><img     alt="fasdfsdfdfasdf" src="http://www.example.com/images/asdfasdfdsaf.jpg" /></a></div>
            <ul class="nav">
               <li><a href="http://www.example.com/index.html" class="q1">home</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <!-- header end -->
         <!-- content end -->
         <div class="content"> 



<h2>asdfasdf™</h2>
```

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle link because it's hard to understand? I am getting this output https://prnt.sc/smbvbz

Comment: It's unclear what you are expecting. For me, the entire screen is appearing `#181818`

Comment: AdityaSrivast, this is the result I am expecting, and desire. Yet, when i view the page on my screen the background is #333.  Any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with your code. I copied all the styles inside the `<style>` tag. Check if doing the same works for you. If so, there may be some problem with importing the styles. Also, if it helps, I tested on Firefox 76 and Chrome 81.

Comment: HTML inline style like `<body bgcolor="#333">` will have precedence over a color setting in your CSS like `body { background-color: #fff }`. `bgcolor` has been deprecated long since and you should not use it. Your CSS is simply not able to override that value.

Comment: @SwS, Please share your expected output.So that we can understand.